# Отобразить текст с параметрами на html странице в ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Есть веб-приложение на ASP .Net Core, на одной из страниц представлена таблица с окошками поиска по дате:
[image: TableHead]
В html коде оформлено это следующим образом:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/SlivyGSM">            
            <input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="2021-10-01" />
            <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="2021-10-22" />
            <input onclick="OnClickData()" type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
</form>
```

Вопрос такой: каким кодом я мог бы при нажатии кнопки "Найти" сгенерировать на странице простое текстовое сообщение вида: `"Показаны записи с " + startdate + " по " + enddate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему посредством использования ViewBag:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SlivyGSM(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Показаны результаты с " + startdate + " по " + enddate;
            return View(...);
        }
```

Html страница:

```
<input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="2021-10-01" />
            <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="2021-10-22" />
            <input onclick="OnClickData()" type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
            <div>
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
```